# led notification in android API 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, led

I want to turn on or blink the led on android devices. So I am doing it through the code below

```
NotificationManager nm = ( NotificationManager ) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    Notification notif = new Notification();
    notif.ledARGB = 0xFF0000; // #0000FF
    notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notif.ledOnMS = 100;
    notif.ledOffMS = 100;
    nm.notify(5, notif);
    Toast.makeText(this, "RED LED SELECTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And this works. Unless I tested it on Marshmallow 6.0.1 API: 23. It crashes. Anyone please tell me the solution?

Comment: 0xff0000 = 0x00ff000000. Your LED color is transparent. Use 0xffff0000. Next time when something crashes post stack trace. Also notification *has to* have a content title and a small icon.

Comment: @Eugen Content title is not mandatory but small icon is.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

The exception it was throwing says Invalid Notification due to invalid small icon which is mandatory on API level 23 and above. Also, always use NotificationCompat.Builder to build a notification as under :

```
NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notif.setLights(0xff0000, 100, 100);
notif.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
notif.setContentTitle("Notification Title");
nm.notify(5, notif.build());
```

Also, Content Title is not mandatory but you should use it to provide proper info to user about the notification. Otherwise, they are very irritating.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a great help.

Comment: I've tried using this (and other) notification builder code exactly. The notification posts, but the LED doesn't blink on a Pixel no matter what I try (I do have it enabled in the phone's settings). Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

As [the official guide for building a notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) says:

> ## Create a Notification Builder
>
> When creating a notification, specify the UI content and actions with a [`NotificationCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) object. At bare minimum, a `Builder` object must include the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by `setSmallIcon()`
> - A title, set by `setContentTitle()`
> - Detail text, set by `setContentText()`
>
> For example:
>
> `NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
>       new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
>       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
>       .setContentTitle("My notification")
>       .setContentText("Hello World!")`

## Add LED light

Call `NotificationCompat.Builder.setLights(int, int, int)`, in your case:

```
mBuilder.setLights(0xFFFF0000 /* argb */, 100 /* onMs */, 100 /* offMs */);
```

## Post notification

```
Notification n = mBuilder.build();
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(5, n);
```

This `NotificationCompat.Builder` class is available in support-v4 library which I strongly encourage to use to maintain compatibility with older platforms.

There is also `Notification.Builder` class but please ignore it if you value your time.

Comment: I thinks its better to use NotificationManagerCompat. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a great help.

Comment: @HammadKhan Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow where we don't say please and thank you but mark correct answers as accepted and upvote helpful answers. Thank you for following the rules and good luck with your projects.

Comment: Okay. I will do that in future.

Answer (score -4):

Step1: Check permission

```
int permissionCheckCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int permissionCheckFlashLight = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT);
        if (permissionCheckCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionCheckFlashLight != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        } else {
            //TODO
        }
```

Step2: Handle callback when request permission

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    //TODO
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

//TODO you will build notification with LED.

Step3: add permission on the manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

It will help you.

Comment: What does flashing LED have to do with camera flash?

Comment: It has nothing to do with permissions. On API 23 and above small icon is mandatory. Since, it was missing it was crashing with IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Please delete this post!